# Exclude property files from resources

Tags: maven-2

How to exclude files from src/main/resources, for ex : I have a folder named "map" in there, which I wanna keep and I want to delete everything from war(or not to package it inside at firstplace).

Or alternative but same result, exclude all *.resources files from src/main/resources and put in war everything else?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may configure your resources like this:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources/map</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

or this:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <excludes>
               <exclude>**/*.log</exclude>
           </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

For more details, click [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html).

Comment: Just note that you have to add `<filtering>true</filtering>` on above `  </resource>` if any properties(${project.name}) to be replaced with valid value.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want some resources to be **copied** into `target/classes`, you can define `includes` or `excludes` in the `resource` element as documented in [Including and excluding files and directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html). For example:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/map/*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

If you want resources to be still copied into `target/classes` but for some reason don't want them to be packaged in the final artifact, then configure the maven war plugin to use [`packagingExcludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes).

Comment: `<exclude>**/map/*.*</INclude>` should be `<exclude>**/map/*.*</EXclude>`

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for the maven resources plugin describes how you can perform includes and excludes.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Filtering is something else, filtering allows to replace tokens by values.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant to (and now have) link to the include exclude bit, but got carried away.