# Maven - Exclude certain resource files into WAR from the default src/main/resources location

Tags: maven, war

Currently, I want to exclude some files from the default src/main/resources folder into my WAR when packaging

I tried using maven-war-plugin with the following configuration but failed.

```xml
<webResources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</webResources>
```

...WEB-INF/classes will still contain the XML files.

How to do so?

Comment: Just move them into an other location than src/main/resources

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750189/maven2-excluding-directory-from-war

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737635/722997, a quick way to exclude files from the WAR package is to exclude them in the `build->resources` section, like:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

**Note**: take into account that the following configuration will only affect default executions of Maven (WAR package, JAR package, ...), but not assemblies or other user configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat late to this question, but I was just trying to do the same thing, and have found that (with the maven-war-plugin 3.1.0 version), adding:

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/*.xml</packagingExcludes>
```

to the configuration should do what was asked for (it worked for me to remove properties files we didn't want to distribute with the war file).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) of maven war plugin, you can include and exclude resources as follows:

```
...
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- the default value is ** -->
              <includes>
                <include>**/pattern1</include>
                <include>*pattern2</include>
              <includes>
              <!-- there's no default value for this -->
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*pattern3/pattern3</exclude>
                <exclude>pattern4/pattern4</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
        ...
```

Are you following this and it still does not work?  If so, can you post your pom snippet?

Comment: 1. If using the following:
<webResources>             
 <resource>
    <excludes>
       <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>                    
      </excludes>
  </resource>         
  <resource>                  
     <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
    <targetPath>.</targetPath>                  
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/osirisws-servlet.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>               
</webResources>
<warSourceExcludes>**/osirisws-servlet.xml,**/log4j.xml</warSourceExcludes>

Comment: got exception: 
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.copyResources(AbstractWarMojo.java:395)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
        at

Comment: 2. If using the following
<webResources>        
 <resource><directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory><targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>                  
      <excludes>   <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
 </resource>     
    <resource>        
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
      <targetPath>.</targetPath>                  
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/osirisws-servlet.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>               
   </webResources>
<warSourceExcludes>**/osirisws-servlet.xml,**/log4j.xml</warSourceExcludes>

Comment: log4.xml still existing in WEB-INF\classes so, can't be excluded while osirisws-servlet can be excluded.