# Loading the Postgresql JDBC 4.1 driver

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc

I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database using the JDBC 4.1 driver. I declared the following dependency in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

This puts `postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar` into my classpath. I have read that it not necessary anymore to load the driver using `Class.forName()` if the driver is specified at `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. The driver-jar has this file but I still get the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
```

I just make a call to in a test and then run the tests using `mvn test`:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432");
```

Even if I call `Class.forName()` before I get the error. How do I get the driver loaded properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection URL is invalid. You must specify a database, otherwise the driver will not accept the URL.

The correct URL would be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name
```

Or as you are using the default port:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database_name
```

The message "*No suitable driver found*" is a message generated by the `DriverManager` which asks all registered drivers if they accept the given URL. The first driver to say "yes" will then be used to open the connection. The Postgres driver doesn't accept the URL because the database is missing and as no other drivers are around to ask, the `DriverManager` "gives up" and presents you with that error message.

If the class wasn't available you'd get a `ClassNotFoundException` not a "message" from the `DriverManager`.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected a driver to 'accept' a connection string with the subprotocol (ie: `jdbc:postgresql:`) supported by that driver and throw a `SQLException` if it didn't match the required format, on the other hand this way would allow for alternative drivers to try as well.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563178/postgresql-connection-java the problem might not be the missing database name, but a missing `/` after the hostname or port.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: good catch. Although a trailing `/` means "use the database with the same name as the user". So using a `/` at the end "kind of" specifies a database as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some issue with Maven setting up the classpath correctly. 
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687609/maven-not-setting-classpath-for-dependencies-properly) , sounds like a similar issue.

Comment: I forgot to add that I get the error when I run `mvn test`. I am not building the project.