# How to place PostgreSQL driver jar file on class path in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

While trying out JDBC program to connect to PostgreSQL database using eclipse it flagged an error saying

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found
```

It was suggested to place the PostgreSQL driver jar file on the class path. Now my question is, how to place the file on the classpath?.

I am new to eclipse so it would be better for a detailed explanation.

Comment: "*No suitable driver found*" usually means your JDBC URL is wrong. If the class is not available (because of a classpath issue) you'd get a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLException: No suitable driver found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982675/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: @vzamanillo I think it's rather a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558568/loading-the-postgresql-jdbc-4-1-driver/23559085

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope u are in need of the way to buidpath.

```
Right click on the lib folder and select buildpath option >import jars>  ok
```

If this doesnt help u then try copy pasting it mannually under the desired folder hopefully under lib folder.

Comment: Copying the Postgres JAR file to WEB-INF > lib folder solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the postgresql driver .jar file in the classpath of your program. and check the url is correct is the below example

```
 try{

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 

       }

       catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
       {
          system.out.println("error class not found exception");
          e.printStackTrace();

       }

       try{
           String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your DataBase Name";
           String USER = "postgres";
           String PASS = "postgres";
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
           Statement st = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from employee");
           while(rs.next()){
               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
           }

       }

       catch(Exception es){
           es.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: If the driver wasn't in the classpath there would be a different exception (namely a `ClassNotFoundException` **not** a `SQLException`)

Comment: My point is that the problem is **not** caused by a classpath issue. It's an issue with the syntax of the JDBC URL.

Comment: yes u r absolutely correct . he may be making mistake in   String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your DataBase Name";

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found`
is when there is something wrong with your connection-string. Make sure

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://HOST/DATABASE";
```

are perfectly correct

Answer (score 0):

if you are  simple dynamic web projetc in eclipse then go to web-inf and in lib folder paste the postgre jar .and if you are using maven simply use the dependency!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:
Right click on project -> Open Module Settings(F4) -> click on the small plus from the right side -> Jar or directories -> Select the path to the driver jar file -> Click on the check next to the new entry in the table -> Make sure the scope is set to compile.
This worked out for me, hope it helps someone else too.