# java -jar could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven

I have a barebones project configured with maven and dropwizard. When I run the command `java -jar target/dexcane-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class com.dexcane.server.MyApplication". I get the same error if I try to specify the classpath using `java -cp target/dexcane-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.dexcane.server.MyApplication`.

When I check the contents of the jar using `jar tf`, I get

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/dexcane/
com/dexcane/server/
com/dexcane/server/configuration/
com/dexcane/server/resources/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.example/
META-INF/maven/org.example/dexcane-backend/
config.yml
com/dexcane/server/configuration/WebConfiguration.class
com/dexcane/server/resources/UsersResource.class
com/dexcane/server/resources/HelloWorldResource.class
com/dexcane/server/MyApplication.class
META-INF/maven/org.example/dexcane-backend/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.example/dexcane-backend/pom.properties
```

I'm not sure why the jar can't find the main class? FWIW, my main class extends the `io.dropwizard.Application` class.

```java
package com.dexcane.server;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import com.dexcane.server.configuration.WebConfiguration;
import com.dexcane.server.resources.HelloWorldResource;

public class MyApplication extends Application<WebConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(WebConfiguration webConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        final HelloWorldResource resource = new HelloWorldResource();
        environment.jersey().register(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: the package line is missing . Do you have 'package com.dexcane.server' ? .

Comment: You need to configure the main class and ensure it's written to the jar's manifest file - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920434/maven-adding-mainclass-in-pom-xml-with-the-right-folder-path)

Comment: @pierre yes I have the package line.

Comment: Is `Error: Could not find or load main class com.dexcane.server.MyApplication` the whole error message? I'd expect a second line `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.dropwizard.Application`. You can't load a class if it's parent classes are not on the classpath.

Comment: @tgdavies I don't see the `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Try adding your dependencies to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly how this fixed my error but following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687609/maven-not-setting-classpath-for-dependencies-properly) resolved my error and allowed my to run the jar