# maven assembly dir with a jar dependency from project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to use maven to assemble a directory for a install package.  The install package requires several things: configuration files, dependency libraries and an executable jar of my class files.  I am having trouble figuring out how to add the executable jar.

Here is what I have so far:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.1</version>
  <name>my project</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/client.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-client</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/client.xml</descriptor>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      .
      .
      .
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then my assembly descriptor looks like this:

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>client</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/reports</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/reports</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/audio</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/audio</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/client</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

If i call mvn assembly:assembly I get a directory with all the libraries and configuration files.   Works great.

But now I want to add an executable jar of all my compiled code.  I can create this jar alone by adding this to my pom and calling mvn jar:jar

```xml
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>run</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.myproject.main.StartProcess</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The question is, how can I get that jar into my assembly automatically? 
I have tried a couple things but I have no idea where to start.  Can I somehow call the jar execution from my assembly?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think having a look at this link would be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814526/problem-building-executable-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 1):

I think you should turn your `useProjectArtifact` to true (this is the default value).
It determines whether the artifact produced during the current project's build should be included in this dependency set.