# Eclipse / Maven: "Could not find the main class" Errors While Building Executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Updated:**  "Could not find the main class" turned out to be a red herring:  In the line immediately before `public static void main(String[] args)` my class attempts to load a resource bundle from a file that was not included in the JAR.  Failure to load this resource produced reporting that lead me in the wrong direction:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name propFile, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:705)
        at com.foo.bar.MyApp(MyApp.java:103)
Could not find the main class: com.foo.bar.MyApp.  Program will exit.
```

I'm developing on Win 7 64-bit with Eclipse Juno and JDK 1.6_45, both 32-bit.  I'm generating an executable JAR with a `mvn clean install` invocation.

When I attempt to launch the app I've received "Could not find the main class" or  "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute"
Similar ground has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814526/problem-building-executable-jar-with-maven) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).  I've read through these answers and the [basic maven examples](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html), but I'm still failing to end up
with an executable JAR.

I've attempted to execute the app with both `java -jar MyApp-jar-with-dependencies` and `java -cp MyApp-jar-with-dependencies com.foo.bar.MyApp` invocations

I find it particularly confusing that the MANIFEST.MF (contined within META-INF within the JAR) specifically lists my target main class, and the MyApp.class file is present in the directory tree at the correct location (com\foo\bar\MyApp.class).

I have refactored my package name and class name a few times over the course of development.  Might this action have caused some referencing/classpath hiccup?  Where else could the main class lookup failing?

My pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      [...]
   </parent>

   <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>MY APP</name>

   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <issues-product>APP</issues-product>
      <issues-component>MY_APP</issues-component>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
    [...]
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.checkstyle.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            [...]
          </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.pmd.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                [...]
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.javadoc.version}</version>
         </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.foo.bar.MyApp</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <pluginManagement>
         [...]
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>

   <reporting>
      [...]
   </reporting>

   <scm>
      [...]
   </scm>
</project>
```

My MANIFEST.MF within the the output JAR:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: myname
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Main-Class: com.foo.bar.MyApp
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why yours isn't working, here is a cut-n-paste from my working maven project.  You should only have to replace `com.pictureu.mains.MainGui` with your main class to test

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.pictureu.mains.MainGui</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```