# Executable jar file won't run on centOS

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, centos

I want to execute a little java program I wrote on my server running centOS and having the `jdk1.7.0_10` running.

When logging onto the server with PuTTy, i navigate into the folder containing my eclipse generated runnable jar file `jbtct.jar` and try to launch it using the Command `java -jar jbtct.jar`.

But instead of launching, my putty session would just get stuck with nothing happening and The log files my Program should create won't come up as well.

I have a tomcat with applications running on the same server working quite well, so I guess it's some kind of config error. But what kind?

Comment: Does the program (in the jar) launch GUI? (as in swing stuff?) Or is it a pure command line program?

Comment: Do you have the class with main method defined in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. If yes, is it correct?

Comment: @AmitSharma: Its a pure command line program atm.

Comment: @jny: Eclipse automatically generates a Manifest.mf when exporting a project with "Runnable JAR" setting. I checked it anyways and it seemed valid. The Programm runs flawlessly when launched in eclipse, but it neither works when called via command line. It also doesent work on win 7 as I just noticed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved the Problem! Eclipse may generated the runnable jar, but the Manifest files weren't set up properly as I was using maven to manage my dependencies.

The Solution was to add some code to the plugin management as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814526/problem-building-executable-jar-with-maven) (Posted by mike)