# Java ClassNotFound exception with Maven Dependency as a JAR

Tags: java, maven

I can't seem to solve this issue. Running `com.benmyers.Main` in IntelliJ with a Maven dependency works fine, and I receive no errors. When I use the Install tool in the Maven window to create an executable JAR file in the `target` directory, I receive the following error when attempting to run

```
java -jar "C:\Users\...\target\AncientGreekTranslator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

in Command Prompt:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/formdev/flatlaf/FlatDarculaLaf
        at com.benmyers.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarculaLaf
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

I believe there is an issue with the Maven plugin in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>benlmyers.ancientGreekTranslator</groupId>
    <artifactId>AncientGreekTranslator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
            <version>0.43</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I have tried the following:

1. Adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to the dependency in `pom.xml` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811419/12101201)), which causes no visible change when running the JAR in Command Prompt, and
2. using `<artifactId>maven-plugins</artifactId>` instead of `<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>` among other `artifactId`s. Basically, I tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014840/class-not-found-exception-for-a-maven-jar) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871065/classnotfoundexception-in-maven-project/16112614) but had no success.

I've received a comment requesting for my `Main.java`:

```java
public class Main {

    private static GreekDictionaryInterpreter dictionaryInterpreter;
    private static Translator translator;

    private static MainForm mainForm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        dictionaryInterpreter = new GreekDictionaryInterpreter(new ArrayList<Flag>());
        translator = new GreekTranslator(dictionaryInterpreter.getDictionary(), new ArrayList<Flag>());

        FlatDarculaLaf.install(); // <- Line that causes exception

        //LookAndFeelManager.setLookAndFeel();

        MainForm.main(dictionaryInterpreter, translator);
    }
}
```

There are other answers for this, and I've searched through several and none of them have proven to be successful in my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share your main.java class. if not just try https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011152/2137378. There are different types of reasons that can result noclassdeffounderror, but I have usually face it when there is a problem in loading Static block of my classes. Double check if there is any buggy or exception likely line in the Static part of your Main.java. Good luck

Comment: Can you extract the ```AncientGreekTranslator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar``` and check if the ```com.formdev``` jar really exist inside?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @tgdavies . Sadly, the line `<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>` in that solution gives me the compiler error `"Plugin maven-assembly-plugin not found"`.

Comment: I have edited my question to include `Main.java`, @epcpu .

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan When I extract the JAR and look inside `\com`, all I see is two directories: `benmyers` and `intellij`. I can imagine that it is supposed to be in there?

Comment: Hmmm - works for me. You can try explicitly setting a version for the plugin in the pluginManagement section of your pom. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html for general docs.

Comment: Just out of interest, what does the manifest file contain?

Answer (score -1):

In IDEA, you should add the dependency to your project Artifacts
File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts
add someone you want to Output Layout And then pack it.

Comment: The OP is not having a problem in IDEA, it's the jar produced via maven which is the problem.

Comment: Commonly, idea will not package third party dependence into jar, Manual add dependence to jar is required, I've had the same problem When I use Idea from Eclipse

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @YuHaoZhu . I went to Project Structure > Artifacts, but I don't see how this can help.