# Need help configuring maven .pom to build .exe file

Tags: java, maven, javafx, pom.xml

I need to build exe file using maven. I've heared that gradle is better for this purpose but I don't know even anything about it. My current .pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ediagent.edi</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>exe</packaging>

    <name>javafx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.myapp.Main</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there enough information for building .exe? if not what I need to add and what to do next?

Comment: If you want a .exe, Java is not the right language for the job. If you still want it, there are enough tools available to generate a .exe from your .jar, but first, ask yourself: why?

Comment: @Stultuske why? 1) The main requirement was to write the project on java. 2) java - is the only language I know at the moment

Comment: Java is platform independent. By creating an exe, you are not adding any functionality that a .jar file can not provide, but you are making it platform dependent, since .exe is a Windows native OS.

Comment: @Stultuske the main OS in our country is Windows and the app is for one concrete customer who use Windows. and running jar file for simple user os too difficult

Answer (score 11):

To create an .exe file, I would suggest you the following maven plugins:

Shade plugin. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>.settings/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.classpath</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.project</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.txt</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And to create a whole .exe including all, or .exe which launch a .jar with all, use launch4j plugin https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-gui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <outfile>target/Project.exe</outfile>
                            <jar>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar>
                            <!-- if <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar> change to this conf <jar>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar> -->
                            <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                            <errTitle>Error in launch4j plugin</errTitle>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>path.Main</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <icon>Project.ico</icon>
                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>1.5.0</minVersion>
                                <maxVersion>1.6.0</maxVersion>
                                <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>
                                <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>1.0.0.0</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>des</fileDescription>
                                <copyright>Copyright (c) 2014 </copyright>
                                <companyName>comp</companyName>
                                <productVersion>3.0.0.0</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>Project</productName>
                                <internalName>Project</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>Project.exe</originalFilename>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I extracted the information from [Clean and Build a Maven Project with Netbeans - Compilation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155590/clean-and-build-a-maven-project-with-netbeans-compilation-failure/26155809#26155809)

Comment: This gave me  [ERROR] 
net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: Icon doesn't exist.

Comment: Path to the icon should relative to the pom file. Eg. src/main/resources/icon.ico

Comment: The `Project.ico` should be in your project root.