# how to make a library jar in maven

Tags: java, jar, executable, executable-jar

How to make an executable jar file which prints something on command prompt?

Can some one tell me steps to make the jar file executable?

I have made a small command prompt program that prints "Hello World" on console.
I've exported that jar file in eclipse, but it's not working.

Comment: and what do you think does this have to do with maven itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building executable jar with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814526/building-executable-jar-with-maven)

Comment: yeah sorry, nothing do with maven, i just wanna know, how to print something on command prompt while clicking on a jar.

Comment: You want to start the jar from the command line or you want to click on it?

Comment: See, I want to print something on commandline, when i click on the jar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As for starters, [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). You can learn basic of Java programming there.